# Telephone number regex with optional text, working fine on online tools but not in my code

Tags: python, regex

My regex code working fine on online tools but same input when i am inserting in my code so its giving error

my regex code:
user has to insert telephone number which should be min 6 numbers or max 11 numbers.
or if he/she doesn't has telephone then i will insert through my (front-end code) N/A.

```
import re
   while True:
        phone=input("Enter Telephone:")
        phone_r = re.match('^([a-zA-Z/]{3})$|^([0-9]{6,11})$',phone)
        if phone_r == True or phone =='N/A':
            break
        else:
            print("Wrong Value Entered. Please Enter Correct Telephone Number")
```

Why this code not working someone please guide me
its very basic regex.
i  tried to achieve same result using other ways  like:

```
^([0-9]{6,11})?([a-zA-Z/]{3})?$
```

Comment: And what input do you have?

Comment: 04131119728 or 021345

Comment: Try `if phone_r:`

Comment: @Thefourthbird yeah that's working but i want if someone doesn't have telephone then i wanna put N/A. value also

Comment: @Thefourthbird am already validating 6 more inputs all other working fine with also N/A but only this one not working with it

Comment: The values you mentioned [match well](https://regex101.com/r/n7KcaL/1). What is the issue here?

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  When you fix the `if phone_r` problem, your code accepts both inputs as legal.  What's the bad behavior...that 'N/A' doesn't work right?  You don't need the explicit check for 'N/A' because your regex will match that.

Comment: @Steve i tried but didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only valid entries are either "N/A" or a string of six to ten digits, then why not just check for the special case of "N/A" instead of trying to include it in the regular expression?  If you allow for "`([a-zA-Z/]{3})`" to be a valid match, then the user could type something like "abc" and it would still be accepted.  You could write an regular expression to strictly look for either the exact string "N/A" or a valid number, but a simpler check can work just as well:

```
import re

while True:
    phone = input("Enter the telephone number: ")
    phone_r = re.match('^\d{6,11}$', phone)
    if phone_r or phone.upper() == 'N/A':
        break
    else:
        print('Please enter a valid telephone number or "N/A".')
```

Also, what if the entered telephone number includes spaces, parentheses, hyphens, or a plus sign?   You may want to use a `re.sub` to strip these out, or explicitly tell the user to enter only digits.

Comment: M can you please tell me why this regex not working please. email address. ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20})?$ e.g: abc@abc.com or abc@abc.com.eu

Comment: As for that regexp for an email address, that should probably be posted separately, not answered in the comments of an answer to a different question like this one.  Regardless, "`[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20})?`" worked fine for me for checking a single email address string.

Answer (score 2):

[re.match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=re%20match#re.match) returns a `MatchObject` or `None` so this part `phone_r == True` will not pass.

Although your pattern might work using `if phone_r`, one variation `[a-zA-Z/]{3}` will match could be N/A. It might as well be AAA because the character class matches any of the listed characters.

You could instead use a regex to match only 6-11 digits, or another way to match either N/A or 6 - 11 digits could be:

```
import re
while True:
    phone = input("Enter Telephone:")
    if (phone.isdigit() and 5 < len(phone) < 12) or phone == 'N/A':
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong Value Entered. Please Enter Correct Telephone Number")
```

Comment: can you please tell me why this regex not working please. email address. ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20})?$ e.g: abc@abc.com or abc@abc.com.eu – Cathrine just now   Edit    Delete

Comment: @Cathrine It does match https://regex101.com/r/Ibsy3c/1 and you could make the last group non capturing `(?:` as well.